# adding mutiple things to a column x row position in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database like this:

[Database example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSMfb.png)

My problem is I need multiple entries in the Substrate spot.
Kind of like a 3 dimensional database. I need to add in things like, hay, straw, potato peels etc. But it needs to be on the same spot like a list just for substrates. I cant go down the rows because that would be messing with the wrong mushroom and the only alternative I can think about is making substrate01, substrate02 substrate03 ... but since this can vary a lot, it makes no sense to make hundreds of rows just to reserve enough space for entries. One might only have 1 substrate and another might have 50 I need it to be dynamic.

Comment: The jargon for what you hope to do is *database normalization.* Maybe that will help you use a search engine to find your way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another table, which contains a column for the key of the one row your trying to add to, and another column for the name, like substrate1, substrate2

So table one row might look like:
MushroomKey, mushroomname

Table two might look like:
Substratekey, mushroomkey, substratename

You might also want to learn about the normal forms of a database

Comment: Do you know a good normalization tutorial? I find a lot of explanation tutorials but none that does this in a practical manner. Like how the new tables are linked to the entry in a software like my phpadmin or OO base etc.

Comment: I don't know one off the top of my head, but you may have to do some processing on your coding side if you want one record per mushroom, and each mushroom has an array of substrates or whatever. And honestly, the normalization thing will come naturally after you've been working with databases for a while.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, the general method to do this is to have a second table, linked by ID that contains one substrate. Then have one record per substrate in the second table.

If you need to display it all on one line, you can join the tables and use 'group concat' to assemble them.